# How to get an entire row from a web table which contains a specific cell value

Tags: javascript, html, tampermonkey

I do not know JavaScript, but i need to find a solution for this with tampermonkey. Please help me on this.

I have a webpage. I give an input into a text field on that page which results a web table with too many rows. I want only rows matching with specific text value.
**For Example:** "Format" is the text. I want the entire row/rows matching to be displayed and want to append result to the same webpage.

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<table>
</table>
<Table>
    <Tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Format</td>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>Format</td>
        <td>y</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Format</td>
        <td>z</td>
        <td>Format</td>
        <td>q</td>
    </tr>
    </Tbody>
</Table>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

My OUTPUT Should be like

> Format x   Format y
>   Format z   Format q

**Note**: There is no attributes for any of the tags. I do not know how to write using index of the tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer of your question :

```
var a=$.find('td');

var str="";

a.forEach(function(td) {
   if(td.textContent=='Format') {
      // here you can change the text or append the text
      str += td.parentElement.textContent;  
   }
   console.log(str);
});
```

Comment: Thank u so much for your help! But instead of showing output on console, i want output to be displayed in same web page. is that possible? Please help me

Comment: Yes it is possible. I already put that comment you need to write the code on that line. Console.Log is for debugging purposes

Answer (score 0):

Enter the keyword and press Enter.

```js
(function($) {

  $('#keyword').on('keydown', function(e) {
    var keyword = $(this).val();
    if (e.which == 13) {
      
      $('table tbody tr').show(0);
      if (keyword == '') return;

      $('table tbody tr').each(function() {
        var match = false;
        $(this).children('td').each(function() {
          var text = $(this).text();
          if (text.indexOf(keyword) > -1) {
            match = true;
          }
        });
        if (!match) {
          $(this).hide(0);
        }
      });
      
    }
  });

})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<HTML>
   <BODY>
      <input type="text" id="keyword">
      <table>
      </table>
      <Table>
         <Tbody>
            <tr>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>2</td>
               <td>3</td>
               <td>4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>5</td>
               <td>6</td>
               <td>7</td>
               <td>8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Format
               </td>
               <td>x</td>
               <td>Format</td>
               <td>y</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Format
               </td>
               <td>z</td>
               <td>Format</td>
               <td>q</td>
            </tr>
         </Tbody>
      </Table>
   </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways to do this and here is one https://jsfiddle.net/ut20zsr7/15/

```
function findFormat() {
  var bFormat = false;
  var result = [];

  $("table tr").each(function(i, tr) {
    $(tr).find("td").each(function(j, td) {
      if (bFormat) {
        result.push($(td).text().trim());
        bFormat = false;
      } else if (j % 2 === 0 && $(td).text().trim() === "Format") {
        result.push("Format");
        bFormat = true;
      } else {
        result = [];
      }
    });
  });
  if (result.length > 0) {
    return result.join(" ");
  }
  return "";

}

console.log(findFormat());
```

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla solution...

In this solution, I’m taking all lines ( tr ) inside a specific table ( #myTable ) and then filtering which ones has the wanted text inside, this filter will return a new array which I join and append in the result div.

obs: includes doesn’t work on IE, so use a pollyfil or indexOf

```js
    const table = document.querySelector("#myTable");
    const rows = Array.from(table.querySelectorAll("tr"));
    const rowsFiltered = rows.filter((row) => row.innerText.includes("Format"));
    
    document.querySelector("#result").innerHTML = rowsFiltered.map((row) => {
        return row.innerHTML;
    }).join('<hr>');
```

```html
<HTML>

<body>
    <table id="myTable">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>7</td>
                <td>8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Format
                </td>
                <td>x</td>
                <td>Format</td>
                <td>y</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Format
                </td>
                <td>z</td>
                <td>Format</td>
                <td>q</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <h3>Result</h3>
    <div id="result" style="border: 2px solid black; margin: 10px 0px;"></div>

</body>

</HTML>
```

Comment: Created snippet, so I think it's self explanatory, but if yet necessary I can add some comments

Comment: Explainations are always welcome and morever quite necessary. You can't expect OP to have the same knowledge you got, so some things that are obvious for you aren't for others. So please go ahead and add an explaination. :)

Comment: Ok, added a short explanation

Answer (score 0):

> Excuse for writing js( script tags ) inside HTML

Have added a snippet for your code, give a try.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()">

<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>    
    <td>3</td>    
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>    
    <td>7</td>    
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>format</td>
    <td>x</td>    
    <td>format</td>    
    <td>y</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>format</td>
    <td>z</td>    
    <td>format</td>    
    <td>q</td>
  </tr>
  
</table>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Have used onkeyup() for calling JS function on each keystrokes in search box, which will iterate to all rows in table. and display that row that matches the entered word in search box.

> Place the index of the array as you want to access the objects.